# combing multiple bitmap/raster images into one dynamically

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, air

Im creating an Air/flex app that captures multiple images thru a camera. now that I have the image, I want to "paste" the few captured images over a predefined location on another image (my main image). can anyone provide an example or point me to the right direction?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[BitmapData.copyPixels() method](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#copyPixels%28%29)

Answer (score 1):

You can paste this code in a project to test, the comments show you step by step how it works. Hope this is what you need!

```
import flash.display.BitmapData;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;
import flash.geom.Point;
import flash.display.Bitmap;

// This rectangle represents your photo: 500x500, pure red.
var myPhoto:BitmapData = new BitmapData (500,500,false,0xff0000)
// This is another photo (green rectangle) as Bitmapdata, also 500x500 px
var somethingToDrawOnTop:BitmapData = new BitmapData (500,500,false, 0x00ff00)
// Select a region of the green picture: a 50x50 region located at 100,100 of the green pic
var regionToCopy:Rectangle = new Rectangle(100,100,50,50)
// Decide where you want the copied green region to end up in the red picture
var destinationForTheCopy:Point = new Point(250,250)
// Copy the pixels
myPhoto.copyPixels(somethingToDrawOnTop, regionToCopy, destinationForTheCopy)

// show the result
var compositBitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(myPhoto)
addChild (compositBitmap)
```